# call() function with null parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. In the example below I don't understand the usage of `call()` function:

1. Why is there a `null` parameter? I thought that should be an object.
2. What `+` before the `y.call(null, page, i, pages)` is for?
3. Can we do an assignment inside any parameter parentheses? Like for `isNaN` when we assign `value = ...`

---

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {        
        if (isNaN(value = +y.call(null, page, i, pages)))
        break;
        ...
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `null` is passed when no object is desired to be bound to `this` in the invoked call. In a situation like that, you really can just call the function directly.

Comment: Note that `null` *is* an object `typeof null; // object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why is there a `null` parameter? I thought that should be an object.

[`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) expect as first parameter `thisArg`.

> **thisArg**
>
> Optional. The value of this provided for the call to a `function`. Note that `this` may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a  function in [non-strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) and [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.

This part is for `this`. If not given/or not necessary, then usually `null` or `undefined` is used.

> 2. What `+` before the `y.call(null, page, i, pages)` is for?

This is an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which converts a string to a number.

> 3. Can we do an assignment inside any parameter parentheses? Like for `isNaN` when we assign `value = ...`

Yes, but is not a good style, but short.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful! 

About 1., the y function return only a number, why call() has even 3 parameters?

Comment: it depends on `y`, which is actually unknown. javascript allows to take an arbitrary count of arguments, even undeclared.

Comment: I was misunderstood. What I mean was y have one argument; but call() has 3:



`function pageY(d) { return d[1]; }`
`y = pageY`

Answer (score 1):

`null` is passed when no object is desired to be bound to `this` in the invoked call. In a situation like that, you really can just call the function directly.

The `+` in front of `y` is an implicit way to convert the returned value to a number.

You generally can do an assignment inside of a call, but that's not always a good idea as it can make the code harder to read.